# Может расширение chrome иметь доступ к командной строке?

Tags: cmd, chrome-extension, permissions

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может ли расширение chrome иметь доступ к командной строке (cmd.exe), и, если да, то какие права ему для этого необходимы?

Comment: Можно попробовать поднять свой локальный сервис, который будет по http получать команды и отдавать результат их выполнения. А прикрутить их к расширению - это будет легко.

Comment: Спасибо, я так и думал сделать, но всё же была маленькая надежда, что в расширениях хрома есть такая возможность).
Есть еще вопросик. Не подскажите, как из popup.html получить доступ к DOM открытой странички?

Comment: @thetur, оформите отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 3):

Не может.
Либо это какое-то сакральное знание.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging